# invalid const_cast from type ‘std::vector<Message>**’ to type ‘std::vector<Message*>*’

Tags: c++

I get an error in a function return statement. I have difficulties with understanding what will I return if the function declaration is :

```
const vector<Message*>& getMessages(string messageBox) const;
```

I have class Message, Box and MessageBox:

```
class Box
{
public:
    vector <Message> *messages;
    string name;
public:
    Box();
       ~Box();
};

class MessageBox
{
public:
    MessageBox(); 
    ~MessageBox(); 
        const vector<Message>& getMessages(string messageBox) const;
private:
    Box *inbox;
};
```

Now I'm trying to implement function getMessages. I try to return vector  *messages of 
Box *inbox. It looks like:

```
 const vector<Message>& MessageBox::getMessages(string messageBox) const
{
   if(messageBox == "inbox")
     return (const_cast  <vector<Message>&>(inbox->messages));
}
```

This gives me an error mentioned earlier. Maybe, I should change my variables.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to return a pointer instead of the required reference.

Comment: `const vector<Message*>&` doesn't mean you have to return `&variable`. The & here doesn't mean addressof, but byref.

Comment: The types `std::vector<Message>**` and `std::vector<Message*>*` are unrelated. A `const_cast` won't (and shouldn't!) convert between them. Please post the body of the function and explain what you re trying to do.

Comment: But how to return it without const_cast if declaration is given with const?

Comment: The error message in your question title is consistent with the first declaration of `getMessages` but not with the declaration or definition of `MessageBox::getMessages`. Please post only the version of the code that matches the error message that you are getting, or alternatively only the error message that you actually get with the code that you post.

Comment: This part give me an error:

`const vector<Message>& MessageBox::getMessages(string messageBox)const
{
   if(messageBox == "inbox")` 

 
     return (const_cast  <vector<Message>&>(inbox->messages));
}

Comment: Yes, but *which* error does it give you? It should not give you the error that you've put as your question title which is the only error message that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem. The type of `inbox->messages` is `const std::vector<Messages> *`. If you want to return a reference to the value pointed to by `inbox->messages`, simply reference the pointer:

```
return *inbox->messages;
```

There's no need for `const_cast` at all, because both the source and destination types are already `cosnt`.

That being said, your code is using an awful lot of pointers needlessly. Why is `inbox` a pointer? Why not just a value member? Why is `messages` a pointer to a `std::vector` instead of just a value?

Comment: Don't you mean the source and destination are non-const?

Comment: @Fraser: No. The member function is a `const` pointer, so members accessed through it will automatically be `const`. And the destination type is a `const` vector. So the input and output are both `const`.

Comment: OK.  I was reading source and destination as relating to the targets of the `const_cast` itself.  If he had dereferenced `inbox->messages` inside the cast, his function would work.  But the cast is extraneous since he's casting the non-const `*inbox->messages` to a non-const `vector<Message>&` before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Your return line should be

```
return *inbox->messages;
```

Note that you should also be returning something if `messageBox != "inbox"`.  This will be somewhat tricky since you can't legally just return a reference to a temporary local.

Your `getMessages` function might be better to return `std::vector<Message>*` since that's how it's held in the class, and it would make it clearer to users of the code that they should take the usual precautions when accessing the pointer (i.e. check for `nullptr`).

Even better would be to get rid of the raw pointer usage altogether.  Favour `std::shared_ptr` for `messages` since it's shared between `Box` and whatever calls `getMessages`, and favour `unique_ptr` for `Box` if its not shared.

You probably don't really need both of these to be pointers, so it would be even simpler to not use pointers at all.  Unless you're expecting the size of `messages` to be large and/or `getMessages` to be called very frequently, it's not unreasonable and far safer to just return a copy of `messages`.